# Extract which day of the week from date in R - ie: the second tuesday

Tags: r, date, time, weekday

I have dates formatted

```
as.Date(variable, format="%Y%m%d")
```

I extracted the weekday from that using

```
weekdays(as.Date(variable))
```

I now need to be able to say which occurrence of the day of the week the date was. For example, this was the second Tuesday of February, or this is the 4th Friday of March.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The occurrence is simply the ceiling of (day of month / 7) and day of month can be extracted using `as.POSIXlt` so put all together:

```
d <- as.Date(variable, format="%Y%m%d")
occ <- c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th")
paste(occ[ceiling(as.POSIXlt(d)$mday / 7L)], weekdays(d), "of", months(d))
```

Comment: Work great! Thanks. Nice and simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the `n`th weekday of the year with `(as.integer(format(x, "%d")) - 1) %/% 7 + 1`:

```
days <- as.Date("2017-03-01") + 0:9
wdays <- weekdays(days)
nth <- (as.integer(format(days, "%d")) - 1) %/% 7 + 1
```

(Put in a data.frame for easy alignment:)

```
cbind.data.frame(days, wdays, nth)
#          days     wdays nth
# 1  2017-03-01 Wednesday   1
# 2  2017-03-02  Thursday   1
# 3  2017-03-03    Friday   1
# 4  2017-03-04  Saturday   1
# 5  2017-03-05    Sunday   1
# 6  2017-03-06    Monday   1
# 7  2017-03-07   Tuesday   1
# 8  2017-03-08 Wednesday   2
# 9  2017-03-09  Thursday   2
# 10 2017-03-10    Friday   2
```